# Hooks com Loop infinito

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Meu hooks está com loop infinito, carregando o tempo todo, o que pretendo fazer é ele buscar na api quando iniciar a tela e quando houver alterações de estado das tarefas recarregar, porém ele fica recarregando tempo todo mesmo sem alterações no estado

```js
const [tarefas, setTarefas] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
setIsLoading(true)
    async function loadTarefas() {
      const response = await api.get('/tarefas');

      setTarefas(response.data);
    }

    loadTarefas();
setIsLoading(false)
  }, [tarefas]);
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código completo do seu componente?

Comment: Fora isso, pelo que eu entendi, você nunca muda o estado do loading depois que ele fica true. Não seria o caso de adicionar `setIsLoading(false)` depois do `setTarefas(response.data);`?

Comment: setIsLoading(false) ta sendo passado ali após chamar a função

Comment: Esse teu `useEffect` não faz muito sentido, porque sempre que tarefa for alterada, você vai tentar acessar a sua api. O ideal seria só carregar quando o componente fosse montado, não?

Comment: Eu uso o useEffect para carregamento inicial das tarefas na tela, e passo o parametro tarefas para que toda que vez que uma tarefa for adicionar ele recarregue novamente.

Comment: Para adicionar uma nova tarefa utilizo uma outra tela que adiciona a tarefa e a intenção de usar o useEffect para atualizar seria para quando eu fechar a tela do adicionar tarefa na tela inicial das tarefas ele já carregar novamente puxando a nova tarefa adicionada

Comment: Mas você concorda que, se você carrega tarefas toda vez que elas são alterada e o carregamento é uma alteração da tarefas, isso vai gerar um loop infinito?
O ideal seria que você carregasse as tarefas na primeira vez e fosse alterando sem recarregá-las. Caso você precise recarregar as tarefas quando houver uma alteração, o ideal seria ter um estado para tarefas localmente e, quando esse estado fosse alterado de forma "definitiva", você atualizaria tarefa com ele e recarregaria.